# extern but static int?

Tags: objective-c, magicalrecord

I"m using MagicalRecord + CocoaLumberjack on my project.
Magical record declares `ddLogLevel` (the debugging/logging level) the following way:

`extern int ddLogLevel`

so that means that I have to declare this variable later by myself, which I do.

Now, looking at Lumberjack's documentation (https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack/wiki/DynamicLogLevels) I'd like to declare this variable as static so I can change the debug level at the class level, dynamically.
If I declare `ddLogLevel` as a static int in `AddDelegate` the compiler complains (Static declaration follows non-static declaration), which makes sense, but how am I supposed to declare it as static?

The only way I've been able to get this to work is to declare `ddLogLevel` in `AppDelegate` as a regular `int`, then in the classes I want to have a different log level I declare the variable again, but only in my interface:

```
@interface MyClass () {
    int ddLogLevel;
}
```

This works, but it'd be great if I could declare `ddLogLevel` as static... is there a specific place where I can declare it as static and simplify my debugging by not having to declare it every time I want to change the debug level dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of doing it is to declare the variable as `static`, but not as `extern`.
I do this in the *.pch* file and add a pragma to suppress the warning:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    // ...
    static int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_WARN;
    #pragma unused(ddLogLevel)
#endif
```

and then, [as suggested by @Quuxplusone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457371/extern-but-static-int/18457846#18457846), I can assign a new value to it:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define `ddLogLevel` in exactly one of your `.m`, `.c`, or `.mm` files, at file scope (outside any class), exactly like this:

```
int ddLogLevel = 0;
```

To assign a new value to it, use something like this (inside a function):

```
ddLogLevel = 2;
```

Don't worry about "static"; just get the basics down before you try anything fancy.

Answer (score 0):

To enable dynamic changing of `ddLogLevel` I am using following approach:

In one header file (`.h`) I have defined `extern DDLogLevel ddLogLevel;` outside of `@interface` scope. In the implementation file (`.m`) I have defined `DDLogLevel ddLogLevel;` without the `extern` keyword again outside `@implementation` scope. Thanks for this I am able to dynamically change or set `ddLogLevel` anywhere.